# Get Timestamp / 1000 - Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i've got a date-range picker, with 2 field each date picker: dat_start and date_end;
everything's fine except the Timestamp of the field I will pass to server to do the search; I know JS Timestamp is in ms, but I should have it /1000...and I can't find the way to do. Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#data_inizio").datepicker({
        altField: '#mod_available_date_id_start',
        altFormat: '@',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#data_fine").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#data_fine").datepicker({
        altField: '#mod_available_date_id_finish',
        altFormat: '@',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#data_inizio").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks to everyone, and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I don't see any problem on doing in on client side but if you have problems doing it there, can't you do that on server side?

Comment: the problem is that the search query is on PHp (so Timestamp in seconds) but the Timestamp I get from the form is in ms; i've got to divide /1000 before i submit search function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the string/date selected by the picker and cast it to a date:

```
var stringyDate = $("#data_inizio").val(); // mm/dd/yyyy
var dateyDate = new Date(stringyDate);
```

Now get the `valueOf()` (which returns milliseconds since January 1, 1970) and divide by 1000 to get the number of seconds since [same].

```
var ms = dateyDate.valueOf();
var s = ms / 1000;
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QpQ7U/

To have this happen on date selection, modify the `onSelect` callback function in the datepicker options.

```
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var v = $(this).val(),
        d = new Date(v);
    if (v.length > 0) {
        $('p#out').text(d.valueOf() + ' divided by 1000 is ' + (d.valueOf() / 1000));
    } else {
        $('p#out').text('No date selected');
    }
}
```

Example fiddle with onSelect: http://jsfiddle.net/QpQ7U/1/

To store the value in a hidden field, simply specify the field in the `onSelect`:

```
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var d = new Date(selectedDate),
        s = parseSeconds(selectedDate);
    if (s > 0) {
        //display to user
        $('p#out_inizio').text(d.valueOf() + ' divided by 1000 is ' + s);
        //store in hidden field.
        $('input#out_inizio').val(s);
    } else {
        $('p#out_inizio').text('No date selected');
    }
    //set min date on other picker
    $("#data_fine").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}
```

Example fiddle with hidden fields: http://jsfiddle.net/QpQ7U/2/

To format as day/month/year, use the `dateFormat` option:

```
$("#data_inizio").datepicker({
    altField: '#mod_available_date_id_start',
    altFormat: '@',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    ...
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QpQ7U/5/

Comment: ok! thank you! how can I have this not click functions but automatic by Selection on datepicker?

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: Simply modify the onSelect callback to do what you want with it. Updated answer.

Comment: that's perfect! sorry if I'm really really bad, but i can't get it to another input field, instead of a <p> (i need this caus Ive got to pass through a form the result of this operation). Thank you again!

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: What other input field? Please update your OP (or the fiddle) with the source html and the input field you need to have the value stored in.

Comment: $('p#out'), in your example, put the result of operation in <p id="out" />; i would like to pass t to a <input type="hidden" id="out"> to use it as part of search query when i'll submit the search...sorry if i cannot explain well, I've got a poor poor english

Comment: The very last thing to ask you: how can i format date? If in jquery.ui.datepicker i change format from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy it's a problem.

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: To format as day/month/year, use the `dateFormat` option. Updated answer.

Comment: hi pete! no, this way it's not correct (even if you try in your example): try to select 21 june, script tells you have no date selected. thanks again

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: Okay, had to adjust the date parsing functions in the fiddle. Updated to new fiddle. Updated answer.

Comment: ahahahaha, another problem :) it adds a month to the result :-) (if i select 21 june 2012 - 26 june 2012 range, results are in 21 JULY 2012-26 JULY 2012 range

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: Tweaked the `parseDate` function. No longer a month off. Updated fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/QpQ7U/5/

Comment: hi pete! your suggest works very well; i've got another little question: i've got 2 date pre-compiled, so i do not have the select; how can I have the same work (/1000 of timestamp)? this is a test link: http://www.iviaggidiatlantide.it.cloud.seeweb.it/downgrade/calendar/5days.html

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: It's the same principle. Make sure your values are in a `Date` datatype, use the `valueOf` method to get the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, and then divide by 1000 to get the seconds since January 1, 1970.

Comment: Pete: thank you for answering...sorry bu I'm not a coder, so it's always hard to me to understand how and where apply your suggest without examples...can you write me how to do? thank you..

Comment: ...i can't get it to work with pre-compiled dates...very bad problem not to be a coder :-)

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli: Maybe I'm misunderstanding... is `1340683200000` the "precompiled" value? If that's the case `var from = new Date(1340683200000);` will put that into a `Date` object. Other wise, please clarify what you mean. The link you posted doesn't clearly show what you mean. Also, please keep in mind that extended discussions such as these are best done in chat and that this is an excellent opportunity for you to post another question. This would let other coders know that a new question is available for answering.